# Android S3 AWS download- TransferListener on Complete return file

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working with AWS S3 and I want to return the file when the proccess is completed. Here is my code:

```
 public static File downloadFile(Context context, String name, String dirPath){
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dirPath, name);
    try
    {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "File saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        TransferUtility transferUtility = Util.getTransferUtility(context);
        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, name,
                file);

        observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                Log.e("onStateChanged", state.toString());
                //RETUN FILE ON COMPLETED STATE
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                Log.e("onError", ex.toString());
            }
        });

        return file;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;

}
```

The problem I have is that the function returns the file before the transfer is completed. How I can make it wait till the tranfer is completed?

Answer (score 0):

I change my function a little bit and now, instead returning just a file, I return an object:

```
public class DownloadDataS3 {
     private File file;
     private TransferObserver observer;
}
```

And then in the Activity I manage the observer.